# Ubuntu 13.04 Geary - how to run in the background?

Tags: 13.04, geary

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Unity  and just decided to try out email client "Geary", version 0.4.3. I find it to be quite nice, but the only problem I have right now, is that I have to have it open all the time. It's anoying to have it there in my "Tab-switch-pop-up?".

Is there a way to run it in the background (checking for emails etc.) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you in Unity or Gnome as minimising/background running can be different?

Comment: Sorry, Unity :)

Comment: There is some info [here](http://worldofgnome.org/yorbas-geary-0-4-can-now-search/) where they say in unity it runs minimised in the dash? I am in gnome so I can't try or give any more info unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a known bug/feature people want.

Geary doesn't have an official daemon, as far as I know, so it wouldn't be able check for new emails and other normal background tasks.

See here: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4570 and here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/geary/+bug/1053205

**EDIT**: Here's the bugzilla tracker link: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=713734

From the yorba page:

> A poor-man's solution would be to set Geary to run at login and hide
>   the main window. Geary would notify of incoming mail as normal. When
>   the user "ran" Geary, the window would instantly appear with the most
>   current mail ready to read. When the user closed Geary, it would hide
>   the window again.
>
> Of course, some users don't like applications running in the
>   background, but pragmatically speaking, this is not terribly different
>   than running Geary as a background daemon that the client connects to
>   via DBus. We should have some way for the user to force Geary closed
>   and, of course, for them to configure Geary not to start at login.

could be a temporary fix.

Hope you solve your problem!

Comment: @Qweick Glad I was able to help you!

Comment: Heh, I had assumed a modern email client would have a deamon. I suppose Geary is still quite young.

Comment: Does Thunderbird have a daemon?  That's different than running in the background or while hidden.

Answer (score 4):

First:

```
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

Then:

```
alltray geary
```

You may allso add this command to the list of apps loaded at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the startup file of geary (`~/.config/autostart`) and change to:

```
TryExec=geary --hidden
```

Also delete the option  `NoDisplay=true`.